# My gVim sometimes acts twice when pressing Tab, Arrow Keys, Enter and Backspace in Insert Mode

Tags: vim

I am using gVim installed by yum of CentOS on my Thinkpad T410 laptop. The version of gVim is 7.2.411-1.8.el6(i686). When editing files in insert mode, something weird happens. When I press Tab or Enter, gVim inserts two tabs or two linefeeds. When pressing arrow keys or backspace, gVim moves two characters or deletes two characters. I don't know why it acts like this. Here is my .vimrc file, which is very simple:

```
syntax on
set nocompatible
set fileencodings=utf8,gb18030
set fileformats=unix,dos
set nobackup
set autoindent
set tabstop=4
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set guifont=Monaco\ 12
set hlsearch    
set showmatch   
colorscheme slate
```

Can anybody tell me what cause the problem and how I correct it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it happen only in GVim? Do you use plugins? I don't see anything wrong with your .vimrc.

Comment: Yes, it only happens in gVim. I don't use any plugin. I use GNU emacs as well, and everything is fine with it. That's why I said it is weird . Sometimes I even wonder whether there is something wrong with my keyboard.

Comment: Yes it's weird. Could you try to compile Vim from the sources? Also, it looks like a Vim bug to me: you should try the vim mailing list.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will try to compile Vim from source now and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: @romainl Whoops! The problem happens on my chrome browser, too. When I input an address in chrome, then one press of backspace will delete two characters. I don't know what's wrong with it. Do you think it is something like a conflict with other software like my input method "fcitx"?

Comment: I didn't make the connexion with your other question… Yes, that's the most likely explanation. See if you have the same issues with another input method.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally found the reason. It is the input method fcitx 3.6 which causes the problem. I first compiled vim 7.3 from source and the problem was still there. Then I replaced fcitx with ibus, the problem disappeared.

Comment: @FrederichChen You can provide an answer for your own question and aprove it.